# How would i optimise finding the topmost row visible in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js

I want to see if I can optimize the code for checking which row is at the top of the viewport at a given moment. This function runs on the scroll event, and the page is dynamically loading new cells (max four on each row). The layout consists of a list of list items, positioned absolutely in a grid (most of the time 4x4).

The code as it is today (scrollPosition is fetcher earlier and is something like $(window).scrollTop()):

```
var topMostRow = _.min(this.container.find("li").toArray(), function(row) {
                var offset = $(row).offset().top,
                    diff = scrollPosition - offset;
                return Math.abs(diff);
            })
```

As you might guess this takes longer and longer time the more cells are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is kind a hard of explain, but I think that you could store in a var the last `topMostRow` when you did the last scroll, and then, you could use find it in an loop with

```
$(lastTopMostRow).next();
```

or

```
$(lastTopMostRow).prev();
```

regarding the direcition of the scroll (up or down)

and check the one which is ratio positive and the next is negative on your `diff`

This way you will only check a few rows instead of all of them.